# Firebird2.5-superclassic on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: linux, ubuntu, users, firebird, debian

I installed firebird2.5-superclassic using `sudo apt-get install firebird2.5-superclassic` and then ran `sudo dpkg-reconfigure firebird2.5-superclassic` and set the password per https://firebirdsql.org/manual/ubusetup.html. Even after doing this, I cannot gsec SYSDBA. I try running `gsec -user SYSDBA -password *********` and i receive  `Your user name and password are not defined. Ask your database administrator to set up a Firebird login. 
unable to open database` Is there a way to ensure this gets created/fix this?  I cannot seem to find a way.

Comment: Have you tried the default?

Comment: Yes, I did, however, if it were merely an incorrect password, the error would state that.  The error states that the username is not defined.  As this is the default user on a firebird instance, I cannot seem to find any other way of adding a user since all tutorials/instructions reference gsec using sysdba, if I don't have that user, i am not sure past the dpkg-reconfigure how to add it....

Comment: @Jacrys The error _"Your user name and password are not defined. Ask your database administrator to set up a Firebird login."_ is shown when the user does not exist, but also when the password is incorrect. So are you sure that your password is correct? In any case stopping Firebird and running gsec using sudo (or as root) should allow you to run gsec without a password iirc (don't regularly use Linux, so I might be wrong).

Comment: No, but it is the password I entered, and subsequently, the default sysdba password so if it isn't, dpkg has some issue....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I found functions.sh in `/usr/share/firebird2.5-common`. Running this creates all of the maintenance scripts and logging files that need to be there. It also creates security2.fdb which stores the security info for users and sets up the password according to the SYSDBA.password file.  You will need to set up two environment variables before running this:

```
FB_VER
```

and

```
FB_FLAVOUR
```

These need to be set to the point release you are on, ex: 2.5 and the flavor you are running, ex: superclassic.

Note: [Mark Rotteveel](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/8283/mark-rotteveel)'s solution seemed to work as well, but I think this would be deemed as the more acceptable method.